# Firebase iOS Distribution Faraday server error 403

Tags: ios, xcode, circleci, faraday, firebase-app-distribution

I'm using Circle-Ci and Firebase App Distribution for our Continuous Distribution
Every thing was working perfectly until today I'm receiving the below error:

```
[10:52:11]: --- Step: firebase_app_distribution ---
[10:52:11]: ---------------------------------------
[10:52:11]: Authenticating with FIREBASE_TOKEN environment variable
[10:52:12]:  Authenticated successfully.
[10:52:12]: ⌛ Uploading the IPA.
[10:52:13]: An error occurred while executing the `error` block:
[10:52:19]: undefined method `error_info' for #<Faraday::ForbiddenError:0x00007fe597865d38>


bundler: failed to load command: fastlane (/Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/fastlane)
Faraday::ForbiddenError: [!] the server responded with status 403
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/faraday-1.3.0/lib/faraday/response/raise_error.rb:20:in `on_complete'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/faraday-1.3.0/lib/faraday/middleware.rb:19:in `block in call'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/faraday-1.3.0/lib/faraday/response.rb:59:in `on_complete'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/faraday-1.3.0/lib/faraday/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/faraday_middleware-1.0.0/lib/faraday_middleware/response_middleware.rb:36:in `call'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/faraday-1.3.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:154:in `build_response'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/faraday-1.3.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:492:in `run_request'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/faraday-1.3.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:279:in `post'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution-0.2.5/lib/fastlane/plugin/firebase_app_distribution/client/firebase_app_distribution_api_client.rb:123:in `upload_binary'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution-0.2.5/lib/fastlane/plugin/firebase_app_distribution/client/firebase_app_distribution_api_client.rb:153:in `upload'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution-0.2.5/lib/fastlane/plugin/firebase_app_distribution/actions/firebase_app_distribution_action.rb:31:in `run'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:263:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:69:in `execute_action'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:255:in `block in execute_action'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `chdir'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `execute_action'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:157:in `trigger_action_by_name'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:159:in `method_missing'
  Fastfile:50:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:47:in `cruise_lane'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in run'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in `run'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:476:in `run_active_command'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:76:in `run!'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:352:in `run'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:41:in `start'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:122:in `take_off'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.173.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
  /Users/distiller/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'

Exited with code exit status 1
```

I tried updating the following:

bundle update fastlane
bundle exec fastlane update_plugins

but still the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After lot of searching I was able to find what went wrong:

To summarize: FIREBASE_TOKEN was either expired or revoked so I had to refresh it again, and as Faraday is used by Firebase then it needs to use FIREBASE_TOKEN to upload the API.

I Followed steps from this [link](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/deploying-ios/#deploying-to-firebase):

> **Generating a CLI Token**
> Firebase requires a token to used during
> authentication. To generate the token, we need to use the Firebase CLI
> and a browser - as CircleCI is a headless environment, we will need to
> generate this token locally, rather than at runtime, then add it to
> CircleCI as an environment variable.
>
> Download and install the Firebase CLI locally with the command curl
> -sL https://firebase.tools | bash Trigger a login by using the command firebase login:ci Complete the sign in via the browser window, then
> copy the token provided in the Terminal output Go to your project
> settings in CircleCI and create a new environment variable named
> FIREBASE_TOKEN with the value of the token.

Answer (score 7):

I hit the same problem just now. And I remembered I changed my firebase user on my local.

Simply re-login with your correct account:

```
firebase logout
```

and then

```
firebase login
```

Comment: This did not help for me =/